# Вопрос по строковым методам в JS

Tags: javascript

Изучаю методы indexOf и lastIndexOf. Даны две задачи, но теряюсь в их решении.
Дана строка. Проверьте, начинается ли эта строка на http://. И вторая подобная.
Дана строка. Проверьте, заканчивается ли эта строка на .html.
Моё решение:

```
let str = 'http// abcdef.html';
console.log(str.indexOf('http//'));
console.log(str.lastIndexOf('.html'));
```

Может и правильно решил, но не уверен! Или через if как-то надо проверять? Но как тогда задать условие?
Заранее спасибо).

Comment: Здесь нет проверки на то, что строка в начале или в конце. Ты просто в консоль выводишь индекс. А сама проверка-то где?

Comment: Ну и lastIndexOf даёт позицию последнего вхождения, а не то, что строка оканчивается на эти символы. Если хочется его использовать, то как минимум lastIndexOf + длина искомой подстроки должна равняться длине самой общей строки

Comment: Пользоваться [endsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) не запрещено?

Comment: @nazarpunk тогда уж и https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith ))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский там в секции полифилов какраз есть код для решения этой задачи.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Можно попробовать так:
//1 задача
    let str = prompt();// всё что вы введёте
    let num5 = str.indexOf('http://')
    if(num5==0){
        console.log('+++');
    }
    else{
            console.log('---');
        }
    //2 задача
    let str = prompt();// всё что вы введёте
    let num5 = str.lastIndexOf('.html')
    if(num5 !=0 && num5 <=str.length-5 ){
        console.log("+++");
    }
```